# Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated since IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a site where we setup auto-login with windows authentication and if it fails, it asks for username/password to login as form.

The way it's done, we setup the authorization as Form with a specific page (Winlogin.aspx).
Winlogin.aspx is setup with authorization Windows. In the code of Winlogin.aspx.cs, it gets the this.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] and creates a FormsAuthenticationTicket with the user's token using request.GetUserToken(), sets a cookie with an encrypted version and sends the browser to the login.aspx page for the Form authorization.

Login.aspx get the cookie, decrypt it and is suppose to set HttpContext.Current.User with a WindowsIdentity created from the user that was sent from Winlog.aspx after authorization has succeeded.

This has been working perfectly on IIS6 for more then a year now
but
we are updating our servers and moving to IIS 7 but now i get a Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.

This is the code that is used

```
// Extract the roles from the cookie, and assign to our current principal, which is attached to the HttpContext.
FormsAuthenticationTicket winAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
String token = winAuthTicket.UserData;
IntPtr userToken = new IntPtr(int.Parse(token);

-----> Line that gives error now. <-----
WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(userToken, "NTLM", WindowsAccountType.Normal, true); 

HttpContext.Current.User = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
```

I have been at it for 2 days trying to figure it out.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate in ASP.NET randomly "Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993293/windowsidentity-impersonate-in-asp-net-randomly-invalid-token-for-impersonation)

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this you have to use a `WindowsIdentity` from a token that was not duplicated. So you have to pass `HttpContext.User` a `WindowsPrinciple` that was passed a `WindowsIdentity` that was generated by an original token (not duplicated). I've been trying to figure out a way to bypass this, but it looks like the only way is to store the credentials rather than the identity and Logon (see `LogonUser`) each time you need a `WindowsIdentity`.

You are unable to re-use an original token because `HttpContext.User` is disposed after each request (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you cannot reuse the same instance of WindowsPrincipal in another request, because SafeHandle instance, that probably holds some references that are assigned to WindowsPrincipal, had been disposed with the previous request and also you cannot duplicate WindowsIdentity.Token - it has to be regenerated. You have to clone the WindowsIdentity - this will get rid of reference dependencies. Then you can regenerate the web site authentication token by WindowsIdentity.Token or whatever.

I had had the same problem and I have solved it this way.

```
var user = new WindowsPrincipal(((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Clone());
//now assign the user again to the current context's user or do some other stuff like storing the clone to session for future requests...
```